# Entrust Route Protection in Laravel 5 - Check for Auth first

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For some reason I have had a mind block and can't figure out what is probably a very simple fix.

I have a Laravel 5 App and am using Zizaco's Entrust package for Access Control.

I want to protect a route so am using route Protection in routes.php as follows:

```php
Entrust::routeNeedsRole('passtypes', array('admin'), null, false);
```

Which works as expected, apart from when a user's session has expired or they are not logged in and try to access the route.

In this case I would want Laravel's Authentication to be checked first, and redirect to the login page; however Entrust redirects to the 403 error first; which is confusing for a user that has ability to view that page, but is told they do not have access, rather than that they are not logged in/session has expired.

I initiate the Authentication in the Controller rather than in the route:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

So just need to know how to get the same functionality, but by having auth get checked before the route permission requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Entrust::routeNeedsRole` fires before controller. Can you move `Entrust` to middleware? You could then check in middleware if user is logged in and then check if he has required role.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - as Entrust is a seperate package and is working throughout my app, I'm wary to mess around with how that functions.

Comment: I checked Entrust documentation, and it gives methods for checking roles directly on user so in middleware after you confirm that user is logged in you can just check if user has required roles: `$user->hasRole(['owner', 'admin']);`. If it returns false just throw an error.

Comment: Required roles will be different for some routes; and entire route protection not required on some routes, so blanketing this in middleware is not going to work unfortunately. I'd like to be able to do this in the routes file if possile; failing that, in the controller.

Comment: You can create many middlewares for each role (not very maintainable as application grows)  or [pass parameters to middleware](http://blog.elliothesp.co.uk/coding/passing-parameters-middleware-laravel-5/) (I have not tried it).

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunatey I don't think those solutions are the way to go.

Comment: I can't see why middleware with custom parameter as needed role would not work. The only other way I can think of is to put routes in ``Route::group`` which will use auth middleware.

Comment: Also, [Entrust can be used in filters](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#route-filter) (which are middleware in laravel 5).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had a similar problem. The only difference, my entire app had to be protected. I ended up modifying Authenticate Middleware handle method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {

            /**
            * This is to protect the entire app, except login form, 
            * to avoid loop
            */
            if($request->path() != 'auth/login')
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

And inside Kernel.php moved Authenticate from $routeMiddleware to $middleware

Then you can protect your routes with Entrust.